# Apache Camel Propagate exceptions to parent route without using noErrorHandler

Tags: exception, apache-camel

I want to implement error handling for a route, which handles only specific's exception and propagate others to parent route not original caller.
It is like combining the functionality of noErrorHandler and onException clause.

```
onException(HttpOperationFailedException.class)
.handle(true)
.process(bean, "generateToken");


from(direct:helloWorld)
.errorHandler(noErrorHandler())

.to(http://localhost/fetch/data)
```

I know that noErrorHandler disables the error handling and onException will not work in this case, if defaultErrorHandler is used with onException, unhandled exceptions propagated back to original caller not parent route.

Is there any way to implement the required functionality ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to handle some exceptions in your route and others in the calling parent route because as you said **noErrorHandler** disables the error handling.

A solution for this is to duplicate the common part of the exception handling from the calling route in your route.